# intermediate container in building docker image from docker file

Tags: docker

As the pic below i don't see the intermediate container in the process of building image from dockerfile.Is it because of the new version of docker or is it because something else?
Because in the older version of docker,we see intermediate container and also removing them after finishing their job.
[image]

Comment: From my understating,  you are creating a copy of centos:latest to your new image emad:v1 on docker.io and as there is no commands inside your docker file you don't have any intermediate container. perhaps you can check with `docker images` command if it has been stored locally

Comment: @admstg as you see in the pic where i cat my Dockerfile, there is a LABEL name="emad" in my it, and because of that and up to my knowledge there should be intermediate container for that line, and also i have centos image locally but i dont understand the sentences in creating image part.I use the last version of docker and it is different from what i have learned before and used in the older version of docker